# How would I optimize the following pandas function?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to optimize the following routine which is executed every frame and it computes the distance traveled by an object, time, and velocity, delta t.

The input is just a dataframe with x_world,y_world coordinates, and frame counter (frame).

first it takes the difference and calculate the speed ds

```
def compute_s_t(df,
                    gb=('session_time', 'trajectory_id'),
                    params=('t', 's', 's_normalized', 'v_direct', 't_abs', ),
                    fps=25, inplace=False):


        _df = df.copy()

        orig_columns = _df.columns.values.tolist()
        # compute travelled distance

        _df['dx'] = _df['x_world'].diff()
        _df['dy'] = _df['y_world'].diff()

        _df['ds'] = np.sqrt(np.array(_df['dx'] ** 2 + _df['dy'] ** 2, dtype=np.float32))

        _df['ds'].at[0] = 0  # to avoid NaN returned by .diff()
        _df['ds'] = _df['ds'][~_df['ds'].index.duplicated()]
        _df['s'] = _df['ds'].cumsum()
        _df['s'].at[0] = 0
       # _df['s'] = (_df.groupby('trajectory_id')['s']
        #             .transform(subtract_nanmin))

        # compute travelled time
        _df['dt'] = _df['frame'].diff() / fps
        _df['dt'].at[0] = 0  # to avoid NaN returned by .diff()

        _df['t'] = _df['dt'].cumsum()
        _df['t'].at[0] = 0
        #_df['t'] = (_df.groupby('trajectory_id')['t']
          #           .transform(subtract_nanmin))

        _df['t_abs'] = _df['frame'] / fps
        _df['t_abs'].at[0] = 0
        # compute velocity
        # why values[:, 0]? why duplicate column?
        _df['v_direct'] = _df['ds'].values / _df['dt'].values
        _df.at[_df['t'] == 0, 'v'] = 0

        # compute normalized s
        _df['s_normalized'] = (_df.groupby('trajectory_id')['s']
                                .transform(divide_nanmax))

        # skip intermediate results
        cols = orig_columns + list(params)



        return _df[cols]
```

That function takes about 50ms.

```
x_world 120
y_world 320
trajector_id 1
frame is a counter 2
def divide_nanmax(x):
    return np.nanmax(x) / x
```

Comment: Have you tried cprofile?

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I did, but can't post the result.. too much function calls

Comment: @walled saleh
Oh cool ! You should now try the line by line to see which one you can reduce ! I am looking if there is some logic that can be reduced, but I do not see any

Comment: is it possible to optimize that line?     _df['s'] = _df['ds'].cumsum()

Comment: Could you provide an example of `df`, e.g. just using random numbers? Besides `'x_world'`, `'y_world'`, and `'frame'`, we will also need to know what `'trajectory_id'` covers. And what is `divide_nanmax`?

Comment: @fuglede edited the post. Would be grateful if you optimize that code